# Date fomat issue using UpdateCommand in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, date, format

I'm using ASP.NET (C#), MySQL.

I'm trying to use a FormView component feed by a SQLDataSource ... the goal is to create a form to handle data from a single table without too much coding and relying on the framework as much as I can.

I found how to show data and to edit them but when I come to 'date' fields I found an early stop in my mission.
Since I'm italian I use a standard 'italian' date format (dd/MM/yyyy) that's quite different from MySQL internal date format (yyyy-MM-dd) this lead to a date format error when I try to update fields.

The form which include the 'date' field is defined this way:

```
<asp:FormView
   ID="_frmData"
   runat="server"
   DataKeyNames="id"
   DataSourceID="_sdsContatto"
   DefaultMode="Edit">
   <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:Table runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow>
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox 
                        ID="_txtDate"
                        runat="server"
                        Text='<%#Bind("date_field","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%>' />
                 </asp:TableCell>
             </asp:TableRow>
        </asp:Table>
   </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

The SQLDataSource is defined this way:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="_sdsData 
                   runat="server"
                   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:data_db %>"
                   ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:data_db.ProviderName %>"
                   SelectCommand=" SELECT
                                         date_field
                                   FROM
                                         table
                                   WHERE
                                         id=@id;"

                   UpdateCommand=" UPDATE
                                         table
                                   SET
                                         date_field = @date_value
                                   WHERE
                                         id=@id;">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Using the 'italian' date format lead to this error:

> Incorrect date value: '9/12/1971' for column 'date_field' at row 1

There's a way to fix this type of problem ?

I tried with MySQL STR_TO_DATE() without luck.

Best Regards for any help or suggestion.

Mike

Comment: I might try leaving the FormView bound value in expected format to keep functionality between application and database. To handle your local formatting issue, use code behind data bound event handler of your FormView to re-format as per your requirements.

Comment: Hallo, you mean to define an hanlder for the OnDataBound event to fillup a textbox with 'local' formatting and then use the OnUpdateCommand handler to set the content of the textbox in the proper format when updating? Using UpdateParameters I suppose!?

Comment: Correct. So the Value of your date column is bound with the database format to keep things working for updates and inserts. Then you are rewriting the format in databound handler of FormView to display it in your local required format.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I'm trying to figure out the solution but it's still not clear for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution relay into 'separate' visualization from data submission. To cut it short the best way to ovveride such problems is this one:

```
<asp:FormView
    ID="_fvData"
    runat="server"
    DataKeyNames="id"
    DataSourceID="_sdsTable1"
    DefaultMode="Insert" Width="100%">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox
              ID="_txtDate"
              runat="server"
              Text='<%#Eval("date_field","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")%>' />
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

In the sqldatasource (either in `InsertParameters` or `UpdateParameters` sections) the we need to reference the field trough a `ControlParameter` entry, in this way:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="_sdsTable1" 
    runat="server"
    InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    InsertCommand="create_table1">
    <InsertParameters>
         <asp:ControlParameter 
              Name="date_field" 
              ConvertEmptyStringToNull="true" 
              Type="DateTime" 
              ControlID="_fvData$_txtDate" 
              PropertyName="Text" />
    </InsertParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```